# Index Out Of Range When Seems to Exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, indexing

Brand new programmer.

Trying to scrape a specific aspect with the class below. [There are 5 in total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTrJy.png) in the inspect window. When I try to print the 3rd index, it gives me an 'out of range' error. Any clue as to why?

```py
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

vegas_insider = requests.get('https://www.vegasinsider.com/college-football/matchups/', 'r').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(vegas_insider, 'lxml')

closing_line = soup.find('td', class_ = 'viCellBg2 cellBorderL1 cellTextNorm padCenter').text[2]

print(float(closing_line))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` returns only one element, the first one it finds.
If you want all elements with a specific tag you have to use `find_all()` instead.

https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find#find

Comment: What if I want to find the 3rd element in the specific class? I don't want the first one, and I don't want all of them. But one in between.

Comment: Then just get the 3rd element from the array which is returned `find_all()[2]`

Comment: thank you. i had .text[2] not [2].text 

it worked that way. i appreciate the help!!!

Comment: No worries, would appreciate if you accepted the answer as well :)